# Не переходит по ссылке

Tags: javascript, html, href

есть тег:

```
<a onclick="Hcirenviurn();" class="YesOrNo17787" id="Yes1781811115154cewfreg1">Да</a>
```

есть javascript:

```
function Hcirenviurn() {

window.open("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?view=cm&tf=1&to=dperelygin2@gmail.com&cc&bcc&su=Вопрос+Тех.Поддержке+ProgrammHeg&body=%20Привет%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20!
%0A%20%20КУку%20%20%20%20%20!&fs=1","_blank");
window.open("/","_self");
}
```

функция срабатывает по клику я проверял, но на эту ссылку не переходит(

#### *объясните почему*

Answer (score 0):

Потому что всплывающие окна в браузере заблокированы, можно _self использовать.

```js
function Hcirenviurn() {
window.open("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?view=cm&tf=1&to=dperelygin2@gmail.com&cc&bcc&su=Вопрос+Тех.Поддержке+ProgrammHeg&body=%20Привет%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20!%0A%20%20КУку%20%20%20%20%20!&fs=1","_self");
}
```

```html
<a onclick="Hcirenviurn();" class="YesOrNo17787" id="Yes1781811115154cewfreg1">Да</a>
```